# how to run individual test cases from jenkins by passing parameters to testng.xml through pom.xml

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, testng, pom.xml

I want to run test cases depending on variables passed from jenkins, like if i select TestCaseForHistoryPage in choice from jenkins, it should only run.

My testng,xml looks like:

```
<test name="TestCaseForInlineRedemption">
      <classes>
        <class name="test_cases.TestCaseForInlineRedemption">
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
  <test name="TestCaseForHistoryPage">
      <classes>
        <class name="test_cases.TestCaseForHistoryPage">
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>


And pom like:

<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>

      </plugin>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
             <systemPropertyVariables>
             <testnames>${Dtest}</testnames>
            <country>${Dcountry}</country>
            <environment>${Denvironment}</environment>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->             
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>                
                 <systemProperties>
            <property>          

             **<test>${Dtest}</test>** 
          </property>
         </systemProperties> 
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I want to pass ${Dtest} from jenkins to testng through pom.

Can someone help on this?

Comment: Single tests can be run via `-Dtest=TestCircle test` or even running a single method of a test case via `mvn -Dtest=TestCircle#mytest test` etc. see details https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Answer (score 2):

Option-1:

You can check this plugin to run selected testcases.
[Tests Selector Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Tests+Selector+Plugin)

Option-2:

Create another HistoryPage.xml file for TestCaseForHistoryPage's test cases. Use dynamic xml file name in 'maven-surefire-plugin' as mention below.

```
    <configuration>

            <suiteXmlFiles>

                <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
             <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>

            </suiteXmlFiles>


    </configuration>
```

Now you can utillize run it via maven

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=fileName.xml
```

In Jenkins you can create job with "build with parameters" option and create a string parameter.Now you can pass this parameter in Jenkins.